# Dockerfile: Cannot update node version, mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-database but it is not going to be installed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, dockerfile

When I tried to update my node version from 12 to 14 in my Dockerfile, during the deployment I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-database but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This is my Dockerfile. I didn't write it myself, somebody before me did it:

```
FROM node:12 as build

# Install mongo in container for mongodump command
RUN wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-5.0.asc | apt-key add -
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

If I put it back to node:12, it works fine.

How do I update the node version?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 26.10.2022**

You should use another docker-image if you want to install nodejs and mongodb in one container.

The better practice would be to split the nodejs and mongodb container to two seperate containers.
Its very easy using docker-compose.

docker.compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'

services:
# NODEJS CONTAINER
  nodejsapp:
    image: 
    restart: always
    build:
      context: nodejsapp
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
  
# MONGODB CONTAINER  
 mongodb_container:
    image: mongo:latest
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpassword
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data_container:/data/db
  

  volumes:
    mongodb_data_container:
```

**EDIT:**

```
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for puppeteer@19.1.1: wanted: ***"node":">=14.1.0"*** (current: ***"node":"12.22.12","npm":"6.14.16"***)
```

Please start reading your ERROR LOGS.
You are using an old NODE-Version. This is an issue with your Dockerfile.

You need to edit your Dockerfile to take a version newer than 14.1.0

Comment: Yes, and when I updated my Dockerfile, from `FROM node:12 as build` to `FROM node:14`, I got a different error, I was unable to `RUN apt-get install -y mongodb-org`

Comment: Please edit your question with all following Errors.